# Java error in reading an Excel date

Tags: java, excel

I have a very strange problem processing an Excel file (.xls) with Java and JExcel.

I walk a data file in Excel, the first column of type date.
It all goes well until a certain row, where I returned empty value for the first cell,

I tried to check if Apache POI JExcel worked well, and I came the same mistake. This clearly indicates that the problem is in the Excel workbook.

The strange thing is that this cell has data that fails, more precisely a date (which is what I read), and is a date listed in previous rows. I check the functions of Excel and it's all right.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I appreciate your attention.

Gustavo

Answer (score 0):

I made the stupid test, you should have done in the first instance.

I copied the entire contents of the book that caused problems elsewhere, and walked all good.

However, I do not know what may have been an error in the original book.

Greetings!

Gustavo